# I've made a custom cell however accessoryView background doesn't match cell background

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have made a custom cell for my uitableview. All behaves as id expect however when i try and put an icon in the accessory view. The background for the entire accessory view part is white.

this is how i load the icon into the accessory view in didselectrowatindexpath

```
    UIImageView* Icon = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[GlobalPictures IconTick]];
    [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryView = Icon;
```

i set the background for the cell by .xib wizard and setting the background but to blue.

how can i make the background in the accessory view blue also

i tried 
    [Icon setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

however this had the following effect
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried setting the background colour of the editing accessory view? i.e. `cell.editingAccessoryView.backgroundColor = YOUR_COLOR;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting a `UIImageView` as accessory view.

You can do set a background color to that before setting it as accessory view:

```
[Icon setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

Also, you should stick to Apple's variable notation and name your objects with lowercase initial, `icon` instead of `Icon`.

You should also set the cell's background color to blue:

```
UITableViewCell *cellAtIndex = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[cellAtIndex sewtBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

Comment: i tired that and got a strange effect, please see the photo in my question

Comment: Edited answer. Take a look again please.